# Firemonkey: Arrange controls when display orientation changes

Tags: android, ios, delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

I am looking for a way to design a UI for a mobile app wich changes the arrangement of some controls when the orientation of the display changes.

What I want is a orientation corresponding view like this:

Portrait view:

[image]

Landscape view:

[image]

These are the most intuitive solutions I found:

1. Put the buttons on a `TFlowLayout` and set `Width` and `Height` of those in the `OnResize` event of the form.
2. Set `Align`, `Width`and `Height`of `Button1` in the `OnResize` event of the form while `Button2`s alignmet is set to `Client`.

I'm searching for a method to achieve this behaviour without adding any code. I have read several tutorials about layouts which are provided by Embarcadero, but I couldn't figure out if this is possible or not.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I would also be very interested to a solution that doesn't involve arranging the components using code. 

BTW, why don't you want to use TFlowLayout? The layouts are made to build complex UIs

Comment: @JohnKouraklis I don't say that I don't want to use `TFlowLayout`. I have only mentionend an other way to achive rearrangement. But AFAIK `TFlowLayout` doesn't support dynamic sizing of its underlying controls, so they would have to be resized by code to fill the screen.

Comment: If you set the align property of the inside components to client, they will resize as the outer control resizes

Comment: @JohnKouraklis: not just `Align`, but also `Anchors` (with `Margins` and `Padding`).  See [Mobile Tutorial: Using Layout to Adjust Different Form Sizes or Orientations (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_(iOS_and_Android)).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes that's right. I forgot them. Thanks Remy

Comment: Then, is there any solution to do a landscape view by design and not by code?? Which is the best method to design landscape views from my app's forms??